# Android Preferences for widgets

Tags: android, android-widget

Assume, widget uses login and password to retrieve some data. I store login and pws in sharedPreferences.

Everything works fine as long as I have 1 widget. When I add the second widget login and pwd in sharedPreferences replaced for both widgets.

What is the typical solution for this problem>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a usual case, the unique identifier for an AppWidget is an appWidgetId. So you can organize your preferences this way.

Assume you have a key for storing a login:

```
public static final String PREFS_LOGIN = "com.example.prefs.LOGIN";
```

And two methods to store the value and to retrieve it:

```
public void setLogin(String login) {
    prefs.edit().putString(PREFS_LOGIN, login).commit();
}

public String getLogin() {
    return prefs.getString(PREFS_LOGIN, "");
}
```

To ensure that preferences store login values for each appWidgetId and retrieve the correct one you can pass appWidgetId to these methods:

```
public void setLogin(String login, int appWidgetId) {
    prefs.edit().putString(PREFS_LOGIN + appWidgetId, login).commit();
}

public String getLogin(int appWidgetId) {
    return prefs.getString(PREFS_LOGIN + appWidgetId, "");
}
```

Hope this helps.